# How to reverse the direction of qx.ui.indicator.ProgressBar?

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a qx.ui.indicator.ProgressBar , is there any way I can reverse the direction of progress bar (i.e. fill the bar from right to left) ?

Here is my code:

```
var pbar = new qx.ui.indicator.ProgressBar();
pbar.setDecorator(null);
pbar.setValue(30);
pbar.setWidth(400);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for that. Just rotating the indicator would be a hack but could work.

Comment: nice idea. but the drop shadow will be inverted. hope there will be an option for that later.